# Powershell - Json to csv - values in separate rows

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I am trying to get the data into a csv from an InvokeWeb request. Currently there are only 2 different values with the individual values in it, but later also times more. It makes the headers of the table, and the correct number of columns, but throws the 2 different values into a cell in both rows. So how can I prevent it from looking like this? I have already read about AddMember or +=, but did not find the right way.

```
$valstring = iwr -Proxy http://my-proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials -Method GET -Uri https://my-URL -Headers @{'ContentTyp' = 'application/json';"X-Api-Key" = "my-API-Key"} -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object Content | foreach {$_.Content}
$pathToOutputFile = "H:\Wichtiges\json2csvexport.csv"

$deckung = $valstring | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($uuid in $_ ) {
            [PsCustomObject] @{
                name       = $_.name | Out-String
                version       = $_.version | Out-String
                active       = $_.active | Out-String         
        }
    } 
}

$deckung | Export-Csv $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

The Json-Data looks like that

```
[
    {
        "name":  "App1",
        "version":  "1.1.1",
        "uuid":  "a74a1969-f57d-437b-943f-d4c3dd3bc4bb",
        "active":  true,
        "metrics":  {
                        "high":  617,
                        "medium":  1250,
                        "low":  103,
                    }
    },
    {
        "name":  "App2",
        "version":  "1.3.1",
        "uuid":  "59eda14a-56a6-4dc6-8238-dd168bd0df3f",
        "active":  true,
        "metrics":  {
                        "high":  6,
                        "medium":  13,
                        "low":  0,
                    }
    }
]
```

But it always comes out like that (second and third together and fourth and fifth row together):

```
|name  |  version  |  active |
|------|-----------|---------|
|App1  |    1.1.1  |   true  |
|App2  |    1.3.1  |   true  |
|App1  |    1.1.1  |   true  |
|App2  |    1.3.1  |   true  |
-----------------------------
```

How can I change it to get one per row that it looks like:

```
|name  |  version  |  active |
|------|-----------|---------|
|App1  |    1.1.1  |   true  |
|App2  |    1.3.1  |   true  |
-----------------------------
```

Thx
Kind regards

Edit (Solution):
That solution works for me, because I can put things from mectrics into the csv and give the Heading an other name:

```
Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$_.name}}, 
  @{Name='Version';Expression={$_.version}}, 
  @{Name='Active';Expression={$_.Active}},
  @{Name='Risk-High';Expression={$_.metrics.high}}
```

Edit (Another question):
How can I prevent numbers in the csv from being converted to dates?
Thx

Comment: you are sure you have to use invoke-webrequest and not invoke-restmethod?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Invoke-Webrequest

Comment: Please include input (`$valstring`) and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```bash
$pathToOutputFile = "H:\Wichtiges\json2csvexport.csv"

# Note:
#  * the use of Invoke-*RestMethod*, which has ConvertFrom-Json *built in*.
#  * the (...) around it, to ensure that the array is *enumerated*.
(Invoke-RestMehod -Proxy http://my-proxy -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials -Method GET -Uri https://my-URL -Headers @{'ContentType' = 'application/json';"X-Api-Key" = "my-API-Key"}) |
  Select-Object name, version, active |
  Export-Csv $pathToOutputFile -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your `foreach ($uuid in $_ )` loop mistakenly used `$_` - the array to loop over - instead of `$uuid` - the iteration variable containing the element at hand.

  - The simpler alternative, to *explicit* enumeration is to wrap a call to `ConvertFrom-Json` / `Invoke-RestMethod` in `(...)` in order to automatically force enumeration of an *array* being returned.
  - Note that this is no longer necessary in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where arrays are enumerated *by default* (and you need `-NoEnumerate` in order to send an array *as a whole* through the pipeline, which is the invariable default behavior in *Windows PowerShell*).
- For simple stringification of a value, [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) is the wrong tool, primarily because it - unexpectedly - adds a *trailing newline* to the output - see [GitHub issue #14444](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14444).

  - Use a `[string]` cast instead; however, given that `Export-Csv` *implicitly* performs such a stringification for you, there's no need to do it explicitly, allowing you to use a simple [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to pick the properties of interest, as shown above.